# Trying to create method that will return ArrayList<T> using SQL statement and key

Tags: java, sql, generics

I am trying to write a generic method that will take an SQL string and a key value, and return an ArrayList, where T is the appropriate type for the rows in the result set. I keep running into type erasure issues. My latest attempt looks like:

```
    public static <T extends CMObject> void populateCMObjectsByKey(int key, String SQL, ArrayList<T> list) throws SQLException, ObjectNotFoundException {

        Connection connection = null;
        PreparedStatement pstatement = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        try {
            connection = TomcatConnectionManager.getInstance().getConnection(ClientManagerConstants.dbName);
            pstatement = connection.prepareStatement(SQL);
            pstatement.setInt(1, key);
            rs = pstatement.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                T.createFromResultSet(rs, list);
            }
        } finally {
            if (rs != null) {
                rs.close();
            }
            if (pstatement != null) {
                pstatement.close();
            }
            //
            connection.close();
            TomcatConnectionManager.getInstance().freeConnection(ClientManagerConstants.dbName, connection);
        }
        return;
    }
```

The compiler indicates an an error on "T.createFromResultSet(rs, list);", which reads "The method createFromResultSet(ResultSet, ArrayList) in the type CMObject is not applicable for the arguments (ResultSet, ArrayList)". Is what I'm trying to do not possible?

Comment: Is `createFromResultSet` a method in `CMObject`?  Is it `static`?  Do you have subclasses of `CMObject` that also have that method?

Comment: Yes, to both. The idea is to have a method that each class overrides to provide the specific functionality for copying the rows' data to the ArrayList.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `static` methods are not available from a generic type reference -- only non-static methods from any upper bound (here, `CMObject`).  Also, `static` methods cannot be overridden.

For both of those reasons, making `createFromResultSet` non-static in `CMObject` and its subclasses is the only way to make this work.  But then you'll need an instance to work on.

```
// Add an instance as another parameter.
public static <T extends CMObject> void populateCMObjectsByKey(
    int key, String SQL, ArrayList<T> list, T populator)
    throws SQLException, ObjectNotFoundException {
```

Then you'll be able to call the method on the instance:

```
populator.createFromResultSet(rs, list);
```